# String HTML overflowing in java

Tags: java, android, html, string, google-maps-android-api-2

i have a problem about the Strings, eventually my application is connecting to google map API and I'm getting the Json from the google map API and send the result to *Snap to the Road* but the problem when I'm trying  get from Long distance and the result of are like the link below and x10 of this result,

https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=14.56342,121.01886%7C14.56287,121.02034%7C14.56272,121.02076%7C14.56271,121.0208%7C14.56271,121.02084%7C14.56289,121.02233%7C14.56223,121.02246%7C14.56198,121.02006%7C14.56186,121.02007%7C14.56124,121.02014%7C14.56114,121.02016%7C14.56108,121.02017%7C14.56104,121.02019%7C14.56098,121.02023%7C14.56092,121.02027%7C14.56086,121.02034%7C14.56064,121.02065%7C14.56055,121.02079%7C14.56051,121.02086%7C14.56047,121.02092%7C14.56043,121.02103%7C14.56039,121.02116%7C14.56036,121.02132%7C14.56035,121.02145%7C14.56034,121.02158%7C14.56035,121.0217%7C14.56037,121.02182%7C14.56049,121.02245%7C14.5605,121.02252%7C14.55958,121.02277%7C14.55942,121.02223%7C14.55892,121.02232%7C14.55885,121.02183%7C14.55885,121.02165%7C14.55885,121.02152%7C14.55887,121.02139%7C14.5589,121.02125%7C14.55893,121.02117%7C14.55902,121.02099%7C14.55944,121.02035&interpolate=true&key=AIzaSyBQM6p5dib2aaxPB-mH0nYHPsAikvA14Mo

How can i send it without cutting the strings?
Thank you

Here is the example strings, that im getting the Json map 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qb55e2wk1c4blia/Example.txt?dl=0
you may download the txt file and see the brunch of points from google map api collections

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? what do you mean by 'and x10'?

Comment: the result of the link is more times 10 the long strings  that im giving but the problem they cutting it of like this , and I dont know what will do @ApoorvaSrivastava

Comment: Its like morethan 10,000-50,00 strings and send this to HTTP but the problem they cutting off

Comment: What's being cut off? Can you post some code?

Comment: basically im using Loop  of the points so here is my Points I'll Update my Question to see the strings, BTW thanks for helping me out

Comment: @shmosel you may download the txt file from the given link to the dropbox, dont worry no virus or what ever just a normal text and they giving the points, cus the stack overflow limited text around 3000 only